# Using IStream to open a file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I am getting the contents of a file in an IStream object. I want to be able to open the IStream contents in a Windows program based on the extension of the file (I know the extension and the mime types) from a dll where I am getting this object.

Can someone please tell me how to go about with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the extension of the file, you should probably create a temporary file with  that name and use `ShellExecute` to get the associated program to open it. There is no standard way in windows to get a program to do anything with a stream as it stands.